# Can you safely drill into the track/jamb of a vinyl window?

Tags: windows

I was installing some window locks that required drilling into the track of a vinyl window.

The windows are pretty standard builder grade Anderson single hung vinyl windows.

Two questions,

- Will drilling into the track void the warranty?
- Warranty issues aside, will drilling into the track cause any actual issues (for instance, condensation)?

Comment: 1) Probably. 2) Depends where, but probably not. Please post a photo.

Comment: Some Windows like remodel that have no flange need to be anchored, I have drilled the frame many times to install, but be cautious don't over tighten and make sure the opening is square, a quick way to ruin a vinyl window is to crank down on the screws in an opening that is not square. Make sure a shim if needed is under the location(s) that the screws are being installed.

Answer (score 3):

The inside of a typical vinyl window frame will have spaced out chambers separated by vinyl webbing as a thermal and drainage system. The sill track channel of the windows should always allow water to drain, if water enters into the track a small hole will direct water through the frame and out the exterior weeps.

If a screw is drilled through the entire frame of a drain chamber water could possibly leak into the framing below and possibly cause dry rot or moldy insulation. I would not recommend drilling anything **through the entire frame** of a window sill, I've seen it too many times cause damage in just a couple years. Hardware through the first layer of vinyl, probably nothing to worry about. Its common the first layer of vinyl is used to attach hardware even on the sill.